# syntax for a grok mutate gsub to replace double quotes with single quotes

Tags: logstash

Need a help

What is the syntax for using "grok mutate gsub" to replace double quotes with single quotes when using logstash.

Thanks,

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps. If not, please edit your question to include additional information (like what is in the answer comments).

Answer (score 8):

Do you want this? The mutate filter will change all the double quote to single quote.

```
filter {    
    mutate {
        gsub => ["message","\"","'"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I did this thing, but now the problem is I am not able to apply grok pattern on the mutated log file. How you please help me on this.

Comment: Please provide more information, ex: configuration file, logs

Comment: This is what I am doing..

filter {
    mutate {
            gsub => ["message","\"","'"]
    }
  grok {
    type => "syslog"
  
  pattern => "^ver=5tid=local='(?<local>(.*))'remote='(?<remote>(.*))'meth='(?<meth>(.*))'uri='(?<uri>(.*))'rtime='(?<udid>(.*))'$"

  }
}

Comment: and my log format is like this
=========
ver=5tid=local="newworld.com:80"remote="10.4100.0:39432"meth="GET"uri="/lbstatus.html"rtime="0.001"user=-""status="200"host=""href="'hua""=xfpt=""-'xfp=""http_al=-"''con="Close"
=========
I am getting " replaced by ' in my logstash but grok patterning is not happening :(

Comment: Can i know which version of logstash you are using?

Answer (score 2):

It is even possible to mix quotes in the gsub array. There's no need to escape it then. Like this:

```
filter {    
    mutate {
        gsub => ['message','"',"'"]
    }
}
```

Comment: this saved me, as I was attempting to replace single quotes with double, but ended up getting my single-quote replaced with: \"

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
   mutate {
        gsub => ['message','\"','`']
    }
```

For some reason escape for single quote \' (to replace double quotes) doesn't work, so used ` as a compromise