# Logstash - Syntax for a grok mutate gsub to replace backslashes by empty string

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-jdbc

I have problem with combination of Oracle SQL statement and logstash' automatic escaping characters like \ and ".

In SQL statement I have defined i.e.:

```
to_char(milliseconds_to_date(m.originationtime),'yyyy-mm-dd\"T\"hh24:MI')
```

But in elastic search it is saved as:

> "received":"2016-01-05\T\18:46"

Same problem I have with range of values generated by listagg:

```
'{' || (select listagg('\"' || cd.name || '\"' || ':'|| '\"' || cd.DATAVALUE || '\"', ', ') within group (order by cd.oid) from customdata cd where cd.messageoid = m.oid) || '}' as MsgAtt
```

The output I am getting is like this:

> "msgatt":"{\\\"CycloneIntegrationRegion\\\":\\\"AMIS\\\",
>   \\\"ToSystem\\\":\\\"FW\\\", ...

I have tried to inspirate by the solution from [case 22534325](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534325/syntax-for-a-grok-mutate-gsub-to-replace-double-quotes-with-single-quotes)

```
filter { 
    mutate { 
        gsub => [
            "msgatt","[\\\\\\]", "",
            "received","[\\]", "",
            "delivered","[\\]", ""
        ] 
    }
}
```

But with no full success. Timestamps are resolved but the msgatt still contains on backslash.

> "msgatt":"{\"CycloneIntegrationRegion\":\"AMIS\", \"ToSystem\":\"FW\", ...
>   Any idea how to handle this matter?

Many thanks, Regards, Rudo

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-mutate/issues/40) with no good workaround.